# Parsing structured data from file python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, parsing

The file has the following format:

> Component_name  - version - author@email.com - multi-line comment with new lines and other white space characters
>      \t ...continue multi-line comment
>   Component_name2  - version - author2@email.com - possibly multi-line comment with new lines and other white space characters
>   Component_name  - version - author@email.com - possibly multi-line comment with new lines and other white space characters 2
>   Component_name  - version - author2@email.com - possibly multi-line comment with new lines and other white space characters 2
>   and so on...

After parsing the output format should be grouped by component_name:

```
output = [
     "component_name" -> ["version - author@email.com - comment 1", "version - author@email.com - comment 2", ...],
     "component_name2" -> [...],
     ...
]
```

Currently, this is what I have so far to parse it:

```
reTemp = r"[\w\_\-]*( \- )(\d*\.?){3}( \- )[\w\d\_\-\.\@]*( \- )[\S ]*"
numData = 4
reFormat = re.compile(reTemp)

textFileLines = textFile.split("\n")
temp = [x.split(" - ", numData - 1) for x in textFileLines if re.search(reFormat, x)]
m = filter(None, temp) # remove all empty lists
group = groupby(m, lambda y: y[0].strip())
```

This works well for single line comments but fails with multi-line comments. Also, I am not sure if Regex is the right tool for this. Is there a better/pythonic way to do this?

EDIT:

- Multi-line comments are tab delimited `\t` on a new line (e.g. look at first entry above)
- Comments are GIT commit messages and can contain JSON or code
- Entries are separated by a newline character

Comment: Maybe `csv` with a delimiter of `' - '`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh how do I deal with multi-line comments that have ` - ` ?

Comment: A good regex will solve the issue. However, without a real life example input, it is difficult to recommend anything. The problem that I see with a `split(" - ")` approach is that multiline comments can contain this char sequence. BTW, your current regex can be written as `r"[\w-]*( - )(\d*\.?){3}( - )[-\w.@]*( - )[\S ]*"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can't give a full example because the data might be confidential/IP. But the comments are basically GIT commit messages (e.g. someone had a comment with a full GET response)

Comment: I've had to deal with structured data files like this and ended up writing a state machine to parse the file. Basically, you loop through each line of the file, check if the line matches the regex of the start line, and if so, save the data in a new "record" dict. For each line after, check if it's a new record - if not, append the line to the comment of the current record. If it is a new line, save the current record to a list (it's done) and create a fresh record with this line.

Comment: How are the entries separated in the file? (newline, double newline, etc)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh New lines `\n`. And the multi-line comments are also on a new line.

Comment: @JonWinsley hmm that is a nice solution! Can you post it as an answer for now? If no one else can come up with something more elegant or simpler, I will accept it.

Comment: How does the given file format distinguish between actual entries and a multi-line comment containing lines that look like entries?

Comment: @das-g it adds a tab delimiter for multi-line comments `\t` from what I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to deal with structured data files like this and ended up writing a state machine to parse the file. Something like this (rough pseudocode):

```
for line in file:
    if line matches new_record_regex:
        records.append(record)
        record = {"version": field1, "author": field2, "comment": field3}
    else:
        record["comment"] += line
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to formalize the file format as a grammar and then use one of the many [parsers / parser generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing) Python has to offer to interpret the file according to the grammar.